# Rounding views with Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I want to create circular views when using Auto Layout, due to this, I can't set specific radius values in my view.

I thought I had resolved this with the following code, but it doesn't execute on the view's first load for some reason and the view appears square until I push the view of the screen and bring it back (for example raising the keyboard and lowering it). Any idea why or how I can approach a fix?

```
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    self.myProfileView.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.myProfileView.userImage.frame.size.width * 0.5
    self.myProfileView.userImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
    self.myProfileView.userImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor().appThemeColour().cgColor
}
```

**Constraints:**

```
userImage.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.centerX.equalTo(self)
            make.centerY.equalTo(self).multipliedBy(0.25)
            userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.40).isActive = true
        }
```

Before pushing the view on the screen when it first loads:

[image: view is still square-shaped]

After I open and close the keyboard pushing the view off and back on screen:

[image: view is now rounded]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the rounding code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead, which runs **after** the layout has correct frames.

Also, execute `layoutIfNeeded()` for `myProfileView` before accessing its size.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    myProfileView.layoutIfNeeded()

    myProfileView.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = myProfileView.userImage.frame.size.width * 0.5
    myProfileView.userImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
    myProfileView.userImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor().appThemeColour().cgColor
}
```

Comment: i see your logic but unfortunately this has no effect either, issue persists as above

Comment: Try to run `myProfileView.layoutIfNeeded()` before this code.

Comment: thanks that resolved it if you can update your answer ill vote it success

Comment: out of interest how can i call this on views inside of a tableview cell?

Comment: You should override the cell's `layoutSubviews` function. (Don't forget to call `super.layoutSubviews()` in the beginning.)

Comment: thanks i didnt realise cells had their own func for this